# How to undo "git push --mirror" when I only got remote repository

Tags: git, github

I wanted to add one repository's commits in another repository.
But I think I made a big mistake.

If I assume that the one is 'A', and the other is 'B', Firstly, I did `git clone --mirror`

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/myname/A.git
Cloning into bare repository 'A.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 65, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (65/65), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Total 65 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (65/65), 17.06 KiB | 1.90 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23/23), done.
cd A.git
```

And then, I did `git push --mirror https://github.com/myname/B.git`

```
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/myname/B.git
Enumerating objects: 65, done.
Counting objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (65/65), 17.06 KiB | 5.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 65 (delta 23), reused 65 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (23/23), done.
To https://github.com/myname/B.git
 + bf2d968...34bc087 main -> main (forced update)
```

when I check the remote repository, all the origin commits in B were gone. Also history of B became same as A.

And I don't have local repository of A or B because I just kept upload files from colab.

I just want to know if there's a way. Or do I need to email github?

Comment: If all you did was clone with mirror and then push, nothing should have changed. You're missing detail here.

Comment: What I wanted to do was adding, but I did cloning. So the things in repo B before cloning were all gone and become just alike repo A. And in this case, you mean there's no way?

Comment: Git itself has no direct way to help you (other than finding someone who *does* have a good clone of repository B), but GitHub might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix : if you (or anyone) have a clone of `B` with the correct version of `master` : you (or they) can push it back to `B`.

Otherwise : github has an [Events api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#events) (the possible events returned by this api are listed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types)), which provides some sort of log of actions taken on the repo.

Look for events with [`type: "PushEvent"`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types#pushevent).